# how can i check if the textbox.text is equal to my first line file.xml

Tags: c#, xml

hai i would like to know how can i check if the textbox1.text that user type is equal to the text of the  first line of my login.xml file and the if the second textbox.text is equal to the second line of my login.xml file
and if it is he can log in if not show messabox saying passwor or username incorrect.
ty i would apreciate that.

by the way this is what is inside the login.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<informacao xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Data1>master</Data1> //this is the first line i want to make this the username
  <Data2>master</Data2> //this is the second line i want to make this the password
</informacao>
```

Comment: can you show us what you've written so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq to Xml to read values from xml file:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("login.xml"); // load xml file into document
var userName = (string)xdoc.Root.Element("Data1"); // get value of Data1 element
var password = (string)xdoc.Root.Element("Data2");

if (textbox1.Text != userName || textbox2.Text != password)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username and/or password is invalid");
    return;
}
```

Note: use better naming both for xml elements and UI controls. Also storing user credentials in xml files is not very good idea.